# Add Google Analytics to all web pages in apache

Tags: apache, google-analytics

Is there a quick way, through a redirect in the httpd.conf or some other trick to add the Google Analytics Tag into the Apache without having to modify each html file?

I have an older Apache (2.0.52) install with hundreds of html and cgi scripts and want to start tracking it with GA.

Answer (score 3):

I would use Apache [mod_substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html)

I'm not sure if this will work on such an old Apache system.
But i have tested it on Apache HTTP Server 2.2.7.

1) Make sure mod_ext_filter and mod_substitute are available, usually they are by default

2) Make sure

```
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter 
[...] 
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute
```

are uncommented. (in your Apache config httpd.conf on Windows apache2.conf on Linux)

3) Maybe you have to add

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

to the end of your config file.

4) Then substitute `<head>` with `<head><script>Your Google Analytics<script>` in Apache by using this code:

```
<Location / > 
 AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html 
 Substitute "s|<head>|<head><script>>Your Google Analytics</script>|ni" 
</Location>
```

If you use Apache virtual hosts, you will add these lines to every virtual host you want to have the script loaded